# API suggestion for AntPoint Studio

Tags: api, mule

Can anyone sugguest me an API to use with AnyPoint Studio?I need some APi which response  json  to make a little mule project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some for prototyping, you can use the 
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Or you can even create a quick REST API using [RAML](http://raml.org/).

Comment: Sorry but I need real data

Answer (score 0):

there is tshirt related REST API is aviliable in on the mule soft documentation links.

you can search for it